# How to get "Text" in TextView from RealTime Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, textview

How to get `text` in `TextView` from `RealTime` Database using Java?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Did you try anything yet? If not, the best place to start is probably: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the value of "text" field that exists under your "app_billing" node, please use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference textRef = rootRef.child("app_billing").child("text");
textRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DataSnapshot snapshot = task.getResult();
            String text = snapshot.getValue(String.class);
            textView.setText(text);
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```